# String comparison equivalence between mysql database and php code

Tags: php, database, comparison

I wonder if it is possible to compare two strings using MySQL and PHP and obtain the same results. In MySQL I have:

```
a = b collate utf8_general_ci
```

For PHP I found a promising way to do it with the [Transliterator class](http://php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php)

```
transliterator_transliterate($a, 'NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC; Lower();') = transliterator_transliterate($b, 'NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC; Lower();')
```

Both will do the same most of the time, but it seems that there is no way compare two strings in PHP, both accent insensitive and case insensitive, that is compatible with MySQL.

Does anybody have a better solution to get the same result in PHP and MySQL, or is this something that should be avoided anyway, moving all comparison either to the database or into the application code?

The context is a replication between MySQL and a proprietary database. I have a unique key in the database on a text field in MySQL. On the other side I have thousands of rows in memory, and I would like to filter unique values in PHP without trying to insert them into the MySQL table first. My approach is to use these values as keys in an array, to keep them unique. The problem now boils down to normalizing these keys in a way to treat the same values as the same as the unique index in MySQL is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing strings in PHP the same way MySQL does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471021/comparing-strings-in-php-the-same-way-mysql-does)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point here, but why would you want to compare the strings in both PHP and MySQL instead of just one of them (or prefer PHP over MySQL when MySQL may be easier)? If you're trying to filter/limit the data you have to process, it's best to do the comparison with MySQL before PHP has access to it; that's part of the purpose of SQL.

Comment: @agi Your question is justified. I edited my question to explain the context.

Comment: Possibly mbstring functions can help you in this case.

Comment: @OP: Can't you make a restraint on the table (composite key, unique)?

Comment: Note that under `ut8_general_ci`  "ß" is equal to "s" (not to "ss", to "s"!), which is completely wrong, and obviously no library comparison in PHP will replicate this behavior. So I would first switch to using `utf8_unicode_ci`, which is slower, but doesn't have this weird behavior. If you are stuck with `utf8_general_ci`, then you will need to write the string comparison, or at least parts of it, manually to replicate that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you achieve it and confirm by some tests, it may not be reliable due to different internal implementation of php and mysql string comparison.

Unlike integers and mathematical calculations, string comparison is usually implemented in a way to satisfy particular needs and can be biased on different languages and platforms. So, there is no guarantee that they will work exactly the same at all times, given you use two different systems.

Secondly, php would be slower for such operations, as compared to mysql. 
You can use mysql features to do filtering unique values. For example, you can create a view or temporary table to execute the operation. 
For example, views and temporary tables are suitable and a proper way to do such operations.

You can read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html) and [here](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/6889/1)

Comment: Are you sure about what you say about performance ? I didn't test, but for me, insertion into a ( temporary ) table sounds slower than check if an array key exists, because of the communication overhead between php and mysql.

Comment: Database connection is the main overhead but you do it anyway. Once connection exists, other overheads is small.But you will gain a lot on operations like comparing, filtering, sorting, organizing data etc.If you use view, it isnt really inserting into a physical table,but takes a virtual copy of an existing table for temp ops.MySQL's designed for this purpose and is very very efficient in complex data operations like filtering. Checking PHP array key is fine, but other operations on it are expensive,if you know how php array works.If mysql can do something, it's always best to do it there.